# getting error when running my bash script

Tags: bash

I made this bash script but getting this error when running it:     ./admin2.sh: line 78: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./admin2.sh: line 78:`else'.
I've edited it many times but i cant seem to find what exactly the error is. this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $key == 1029127 ]]
clear
echo -e ""
echo -e -n "${LIGHTRED}[!] ${WHITE}Loading admin menu"
spinner () {
local SP_WIDTH="$3"
local SP_DELAY="$4"
local SP_STRING=${2:-"'|/=\'"}
local SP_COLOR=0
tput civis
while [ -d /proc/$1 ]; do
    ((RANDOM%2 == 0)) && SP_COLOR=3$((RANDOM%8)) ||
SP_COLOR=9$((RANDOM%8))
    printf "\e[1;${SP_COLOR}m\e7  %${SP_WIDTH}s  \e8\e[0m" "$SP_STRING"
    sleep ${SP_DELAY:-.2}
    SP_STRING=${SP_STRING#"${SP_STRING%?}"}${SP_STRING%?}
done
tput cnorm
}

sleep 2.5 &
spinner "$!" '-\\|/' '1.1' '.2'
tput civis
sleep 1
tput cnorm
while true
do
clear
echo -e "${LIGHTCYAN} Welcome"
echo -e ""
echo -e -n "${WHITE}- Current IP:${LIGHTRED} "
w|awk '{if(NR>2){print $3}}' $3
echo -e -n "${WHITE}- Users connected:${LIGHTRED} "
users | wc -w
echo -e "${WHITE}- Admin privileges:${WHITE
[${LIGHTGREEN}Enabled${WHITE}]"
echo -e ""
echo -e "${LIGHTRED} //Announcements//"
echo -e ""
echo -e "${YELLOW}- Type: /help to see commands"
echo -e "\n"
echo -e ""
echo -e ""
echo -e -n "${LIGHTRED}Type: \c"
read answer
else
echo -e ""
echo -e "${LIGHTRED}[!] ${WHITE}Incorrect key, access denied.
fi
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

You also seem to have forgotten to end the second while loop. You should end it by adding a `done`on the line before the else

```
...
read answer
done
else
  echo -e ""
  echo -e "${LIGHTRED}[!] ${WHITE}Incorrect key, access denied.
fi
```

Comment: also if its not too much to ask, im getting a error again, this is it: ./admin2.sh: line 232: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'           this is what is on line 232: echo -e "${LIGHTRED} Done!"

Comment: also error: ./admin2.sh: line 240: syntax error: unexpected end of file           and this is what is on line 239: esac                                                               nothing is on line 240 the script ends on line 239

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a " somewhere, you probably started a string somewhere and forgot to end it

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `then` after your `if` statement on line 2:

```
if [[ $key == 1029127 ]]
then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

Many people prefer to put the `then` on the same line, as:

```
if [[ $key == 1029127 ]]; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

Either way I'd encourage you to properly indent your code so that it's easier to read, and be consistent about style choices such as putting `then` and `do` on separate lines or not.